# Slides flickering after end loop in Swiper Slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

For very long time (weeks, month) I tries to show boxes through opacity in visible slides.
Everything works well but between 1nd and 2nd slides after swipes loop we can see flickering all slides and i don't know how fix that problem.  want .swiper-container not to have overflow: hidden and show all slides visible. I searched the entire internet and found no solution to this problem. I would be very grateful for your help.

It's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="box">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="box">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="box">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="box">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="box">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

```
.box {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.swiper-slide .box {
  opacity: 0;
}
.swiper-slide-visible .box {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```
let slider;

$('.swiper-container').each(function(){

    slider = new Swiper($(this)[0], {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 50,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
        },
        watchOverflow: true,
        watchSlidesVisibility: true
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried all. add addative classess to visible slide and showing boxes trough opacity, works with events slideChangeTransitionStart, slideChangeTransitionEnd, and much much more.

Answer (score 3):

Add below to .swiper-slide class or switch to css only mode

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: cssMode: true works terrible
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  not working

More of the problem is adding the duplicate slide class

Comment: worth trying adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to the swiper-slide class

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a problem with css, but adding swiper-slide-visible class after the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, as I figured out it happens if big amount of images in the slider. I tried to change slider to keen-slider and it works the same (